# Clear Apache's own cache

Tags: apache, caching

how can I clear the apache cache on a remote server, running ubuntu 14.04lts?

My Problem:

Getting the CSS file from myurl.com/myfile.css gets me an old file. Actually I have changed the content of this file.

After that, I changed my .htacces file to disable the caching:

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 518400 seconds"
#  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 518400 seconds"
#  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 518400 seconds"
#  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"  
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifmodule>

<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  # Cache specified files for 6 days(release cycle normally a week)
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  #  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=518400, public"
</filesmatch>
 # Cache HTML files for a couple hours
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache PDFs for a day
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache Javascripts for 2.5 days
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
#  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Still the same problem. I started to google and found quite a lot of topics, all saying, it is an client browser issue.

So I cleared the cache on the browser, tried a different pc and also just wget'ed the file.

Same issue

So I looked at the server, did a vi on the file: File is changed on the server.

Do I miss anything? From my opinion and can only be, that the apache is still caching the file on a http request. http code is 200

Actually, adding a timestamp like myurl,com/myfile.css?525235 solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check settings related to ETag.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  ExpiresActive On
     <FilesMatch "!.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|php)$">
       ExpiresACtive On
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
       Header unset Cookie
       Header unset Set-Cookie
       php_value session.cookie_domain example.com
    </FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    #ExpiresDefault A29030400
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    ExpiresDefault A29030400
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
      Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
   </FilesMatch>
  Header unset Pragma
  FileETag None
  Header unset ETag
  Header append Cache-Control "public" 
</IfModule>
```